# iOS: What are the possible options to Reset an iOS apps Data without requiring a reinstall?

Tags: ios, core-data, plist, nsuserdefaults, reset

This is a iOS 101 question and I feel like an ass for not knowing the answer :-)
The question is - how do I reset an iOS app to the state it was when first installed?
The app stores content in NSUserDefaults and plists. It appears excessive to have to ask the user to delete and reinstall the app.

What are the possible options available aside from asking my user to simply reinstall the app (which would makes me look kinda un-innovative :-)   )

This particular app used NSUserDefaults and plists to store data. But while you come up with your creative solutions I'd appreciate any clues for other situations as well  (i.e. where data is in core data and .plists)

Also if this is a feature needs to be implemented in the app code, appreciate suggestions on a elegant solution for it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Delete all files from the sandbox:

```
NSString *p = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath] stringByDeletingLastPathComponent];
for (NSString *fname in @[ @"tmp", @"Library", @"Documents", @"Caches", @"Preferences" ]) {
    NSString *path = [p stringByAppendingPathComponent:fname];
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:path error:NULL];
}
```

Alternative way for resetting the user defaults only:

```
NSDictionary *dRepr = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] dictionaryRepresentation];
for (NSString *key in dRepr) {
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] removeObjectForKey:key];
}

[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
[NSUserDefaults resetStandardUserDefaults];
```

Comment: Thank you! You have indicated a code solution - is there is any way of doing the reset directly on the iPhone?

Comment: @CoolDocMan What other kind of solution would you expect? What's not "direct" enough in this (whatever that would mean)?

Comment: What I mean is that the app is already out there with the user and now the user wants to reset the data. I want to avoid asking the user to reinstall the app. Your solution appears to be one where I need to add that code into the app and implement a reset button correct?

Comment: @CoolDocMan Yes, kind of. I can't imagine a scenario when you could/would want to do that automatically, out of nowhere... How would you approach resetting the app without knowing *when* it is necessary?

Comment: H2CO3 I understand your solution. But the current version of the app is out there with the user already :-) and she wants to reset it now. I guess the answer is she cannot do so without reinstalling correct? (and then I'll have to put up a new version with that reset)

Comment: If you ask on StackOverflow, a code solution is really what you should expect.

Answer (score 1):

The NSUserDefaults is a keyValue collection so for all the keys that you use across the app you can call this method:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] removeObjectForKey:@"yourKey"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

about plist I suppose that you are talking about writing NSArrays and NSDictionaries on the disk's device or implementing NSCoding delegate in your objects subclasses and archiving them... in this case just remove the files using the file manager

```
NSError *error;
[[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:@"filePath" error:&error];
```

for core data it's easy, you can delete the sqlite file like the plists, don't forget to re initialize the persistent store, managed object context etc... after this operation

Comment: Thanks! But can I do the "remove the file using file manager" or core data deletion directly on the iPhone - under settings for the app say? Or do I need to code that as well?

Comment: to do that you need your app running, but in settings you can mark the intention to delete the data and the next time the app is opened you can run the "reset code"